# Rails Rake Tasks, output a message during and at the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, paperclip, task

I've made a rails rake task that uploads/crops/re-sizes (with paperclip) silly amounts of images.

I wanted to know  how to output a message to the terminal when it was running (e.g. chipolata.jpg processed) and at the end, it takes a good few minutes to run and a little feedback would be good.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use the standard Ruby `puts` command:

```
puts "Hello from Rake!"
```

You can use string interpolation to output the individual file names within the loop:

```
puts "#{image_filename} processed"
```

Comment: How do you prevent these from printing in your specs?

Answer (score 0):

In your loop simply call:

```
puts "chipolata.jpg processed"
```